# simple field update mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a field with unixtime in seconds and I need it to be in milliseconds. Just a simple query to update the columns time and changetime by multiplying by 1000.

I had a script to do this, but lost it. Totally having a Friday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET `time` = `time` * 1000, `changetime` = `changetime` * 1000
```

Comment: darn ran into the bigint problem. now i need to create a new bigint column to support the new values.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update all your current rows then:

> update tablename set column_name=column_name*1000 where 1

Answer (score 0):

```
Update yourtable
Set column=column*1000
```

Replace 'yourtable' and 'column' by the actual names, obviously.